# Swagger best practices

Tags: swagger

I am currently defining a Rest API and I intend to use **Swagger** to document it.
I've already started to define my API specifications with the **Open Api Specification** in YAML into the **Swagger-Editor**.

Then, I understand that I will provide that file to the **Swagger-codegen** to generate a server implementation, and also to the **Swagger-UI** (whose statics files will be previously paste to my server) to expose the interactive documentation .

According to Swagger, this is the **top-down approach**.

But later, I will probably need to modify this API, and I want to do it via by this tediously YAML file previously defined, to keep the API easily modifiable by anyone (and Language-agnostic).

1. Does the way to do this is to modify the definition file and then re-use **Swagger-codegen** ? By this approach, I guess so that I can't even lightly modify the API directly in the implementation server code without risking to have a out of date documentation.

And If I chose to do the **bottom-up approach** (via **Swagger-core** annotation), I will restrain all my further modifications to occur in the implementation server code, and my initial definition file will never be usable again.

2. So another question would be : Is there a common way to deal with Swagger when we want to modify the API both via the specification file and via the implementation server code (I suppose that the file that **Swagger-core** can generate me from my code, will never looks like my initial one that I defined by hand).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To maintain the API documentation, the best course of action that i can suggest is to follow a hybrid approach.

Initially, when you have to do bulk development, go for the top down approach. This will reduce the initial set up and coding effort. That's the basic idea behind any codegen.

Then, when it comes to maintaining the APIs, or adding a few new ones every day (or week), follow the bottom up approach. You will already have the previous code, the only thing you'll need to do is add some more annotations or API definitions.

Going for top-down iteratively defeats the purpose of code maintenance. Boiler plates and self generated code are there to give you a quick start, not for sustenance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it fit well with the way I planned to use it, your comment confirm me.

Comment: _"Going for top-down iteratively defeats the purpose of code maintenance."_ don't agree with this.  Ideally generated code shouldn't need maintenance. As long as the generated code and implementation code can be kept separate,  then regenerate.  If I Add new endpoints to my api I don't want to have to write the boiler plate code for them when I could just add the definitions and regenerate

Answer (score 5):

My opinion may be biased.

For API client, there should not be a need to customize it in most cases. If you find that you need to customize it to meet your requirement, it may worth starting a discussion via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new (and also please check what are the options available to customize the output, e.g. for PHP, run `java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar config-help -l php`)

For server stub, ideally the developers only need to focus on the business/application logic and regenerate the server stub when adding/deleting/updating endpoints (but I don't think all the server stubs can achieve that yet)

Disclaimer: I'm the top contributor to Swagger Codegen

Comment: Yes, for the server stub regeneration, that would have been handy (like cxf wsdl generated classes), but according that the official Swagger codegen directly provide the methods endpoints (with the '//do some magic here') and not interfaces, I guess they did not planned to use it that way. Am I wrong ?

Comment: We've not achieved that yet for server stubs. If you want to help out, please open an issue or PR in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen

Comment: @wing328 Is there a best practice to use generated (.NET Core) server stubs when iterating the yaml (during development) file with repeating code generations and WITHOUT loosing implementations? Is there a good place to ask for swagger-gen best practices when using the generated code?

Comment: Please join the discussion in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5431

Comment: I realise this question is a couple of years old,  but I've just implemented using swagger code gen to generate the boiler plate for the server. I don't need to touch the generated code manually. In fact,  I don't even check in the generated code to git,  just the swagger file and generation params (in my case in the pom.xml some I use the swagger maven plugin to generate) - plus the actual business logic implementation code of course! . Using Java Spring templates with spring boot library and delegate pattern. Separate source folders for generated and implementation code.